# SSRS Reports - Run a group of reports when another report is run

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have 4 reports which I require to be run and emailed each week. The specific time and day is variable and so they should only be triggered by a user on demand. None of the reports have any parameters.

What I'd like to do is create a 5th 'Process Reports' report which when that is run by the user the other 4 are automatically run and emailed to the user without any further input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use AddEvent to trigger your email subscription to run when another report is run.

You would need to setup a one-time subscription or end a subscription. Then get the **Subscription ID** for the subscription from the address bar.

> http://sqlprd01/reports/manage/catalogitem/editsubscription/Reports/Billing%20Issues?id=**ac621ded-680a-41b8-9ae3-653e39715290**

```
EXEC dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = 'ac621ded-680a-41b8-9ae3-653e39715290';
```

Create a new report that runs the AddEvent for the four other reports in the dataset.
 You'd probably need to have a SELECT after the AddEvents to make the dataset work.

```
SELECT 'Reports Triggered' AS REPORT_STATUS
```

When this report is run, it will trigger the other 4 reports.

Comment: Thanks. I've done this and it works as you've said, I created a 5th report which calls a sproc that executes those events and that's doing exactly what I needed.